# What does it mean <<EOF in (t)csh?

Tags: linux, tcsh, csh

I have the following command:

```
wash -n <groups> <<EOF
echo hi 
echo bye <<BYE

<commands>

exit 0
BYE
exit 0
EOF

<commands>
```

where `<groups>` are some groups and `<commands>` are commands. I don't understand what `<<EOF` and `<<BYE` mean? Is it some label which the script jumps in case fails? What does this script do?

Comment: It is called a "here" document.  It allows you to add `stdin` alongside the command in a script.

Comment: See also the [tag:here-document] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a feature named "[here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)". Basically it means that the text between `<<whatever` and `whatever` are presented to the standard input of the command. In your case, the stdin seen by the first command is,

```
echo hi 
echo bye <<BYE

<commands>

exit 0
BYE
exit 0
```

Comment: So if `<commands>` is `echo inside`, I get `hi` and the `bye`. It does not run the command `echo inside`.  Not sure I understood the flow.

Comment: @vesii The here-document does not matter much in this example as `echo` does not read from its standard input stream.  The contents of the here-document is simply discarded.

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr: *command* << *TEXT*: the string *TEXT* is treated as end-of-file.

I tested, and it seems to be like this: When you do:

```
% command << TEXT
```

csh reads the standard input, and when it catches *TEXT*, the full stdin before *TEXT* is redirected to *command*. (*TEXT* has to be on a separate row to work)